# Convert one set of objects to another set of objects of different class in single line. C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes with different properties in each. Also I have a collection of one set of objects of the class A. Now I want to copy these to an array of objects of Class B.

The 2 classes are not inter related and also the fields are different in each. SO i have to explicitly map the fields i want to copy. Right now I am using a foreach to copy individual element. **Is there a shorter way to accomplish this.**
This is the class B

```
 public class Event
        {
            public string EventOriginTime { get; set; }
            public string EventReceivedTime { get; set; }
            public int EventCode { get; set; }
            public string CardNumber { get; set; }
            public string ReaderName { get; set; }

        }
```

First class A also will appear something like this but that is a 3rd party class.

Current solution I have is:

```
List<Event> listOfEvents = new List<Event>();
            foreach (var eachEvent in eventsFromArgus)
            {
                listOfEvents.Add( new Event
                { 
                    ReaderName = eachEvent.DeviceName, 
                    EventCode = eachEvent.EventCode, 
                    EventReceivedTime = eachEvent.ReceiveTime.ToString(), 
                    EventOriginTime = eachEvent.OriginTime.ToString(), 
                    CardNumber = eachEvent.CredentialIdentifier
                });
            }
```

Comment: Maybe something  using reflection

Comment: You could use reflection to do this, using PropertyInfo, but honestly, this will make your code hard to read.  Your code as it is now is very readable and understandable, and fast.  My suggestion would be to use the code that you show above.

Comment: Ok. Am currently proceeding with the code I have (the foreach). Just wanted to know if there was some other single line way to achieve this.

Comment: I also recommend @Michael suggestion, not to use reflection, as the above code is readable and understandable.

Comment: You could also write a ToEvent() method (or extension method if you don't have access to extend the base class) on whatever type eventsFromArgus are, then change your loop (or the linq statements below) to use that.  I sit on the fence on which was is better, but it is another option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
List<event> listOfEvents = 
    (from eachEvent in eventsFromArgus
     select new Event(
         ReaderName = eachEvent.DeviceName, 
         EventCode = eachEvent.EventCode, 
         EventReceivedTime = eachEvent.ReceiveTime.ToString(), 
         EventOriginTime = eachEvent.OriginTime.ToString(), 
         CardNumber = eachEvent.CredentialIdentifier)).ToList();
```

But that's not terribly different from what you already have.

Or, you could look into something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: StructureMap is an IOC tool. I'm guessing you meant to suggest [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: @AhmadMageed: Yes, I meant AutoMapper. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to pass the third party object directly into the Event class' constructor:

```
public class Event
{
    private readonly ThirdPartyClass _eventFromArgus;

    public Event(ThirdPartyClass eventFromArgus)
    {
        _eventFromArgus = eventFromArgus;
    }

    public string ReaderName { get { return _eventFromArgus.DeviceName; } }
    // etc.
}
```

Then you can just do this:

```
var listOfEvents = eventsFromArgus.Select(eachEvent => new Event(eachEvent));
```

Answer (score 2):

also with linq as Jim suggested but a bit different

```
var listOfEvents = eventsFromArgus.Select(eachEvent => 
    new Event( ReaderName = eachEvent.DeviceName, 
               EventCode = eachEvent.EventCode, 
               EventReceivedTime = eachEvent.ReceiveTime.ToString(), 
               EventOriginTime = eachEvent.OriginTime.ToString(), 
               CardNumber = eachEvent.CredentialIdentifier)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a constructor to the Event class:

```
public Event(string EventOriginTime, string EventReceivedTime, int EventCode, string CardNumber, string ReaderName)
{
    this.EventOriginTime = EventOriginTime;
    this.EventReceivedTime = EventReceivedTime;
    this.EventCode = EventCode;
    this.CardNumber = CardNumber;
    this.ReaderName = ReaderName;
}
```

Then at least you don't have to specify the field names when creating a new instance.

```
List<Event> listOfEvents = new List<Event>();
foreach (var eachEvent in eventsFromArgus)
{
    listOfEvents.Add(new Event(eachEvent.OriginTime.ToString(), eachEvent.ReceiveTime.ToString(), eachEvent.EventCode, eachEvent.DeviceName)
}
```